# How to get files from SharePoint that are grouped by file attributes through rest API calls?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, postman, odata

I have bunch of Excel files in SharePoint and they are grouped based on two fields in the Excel sheet - `Zone` and `Month`. I need to pass REST API calls to get all the files that meet the `Zone` and `Month` criteria. For example get all files where `Zone = 'US'` and `Month = 'APR`. The grouped SharePoint file structure looks like below -

```
Folder List-2023
      ---- Zone : US NA
      ---- Month
           APR
                ---Excel files
           May
               ----Excel files
```

My REST API call below is throwing below error in Postman

> https‍://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/ppp/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/ppp/Folder List 2023')/files?$select=Files&$filter=Zone eq 'US NA'&$filter=Month eq 'APR'

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "Field or property \"Zone\" does not exist."
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.